# Magento 2: How to get secure category URL programmatically?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, category, url

I have a custom category indexer which grabs Magento categories and index them to a search service. Within each category I need to index it's URL which I do by code

```
$url = $category->getUrl();
```

where `$category` is instance of [`Magento\Catalog\Model\Category`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/Category.php).

The issue is when the store is set to use Secure URLs in front end. Then this code always return the not-secure URL. Do you know how to get the secure one?

With product I solved it with code

```
$url = $product->getUrlModel()->getUrl($product, ['_secure' => true]);
```

because simple `$url = $product->getProductUrl();` returned a not-secure URL as well.

However from Category I don't have access to any `UrlModel` or any way how to pass `_secure` parameter to `getUrl()` method.

My current configuration:
[image]

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I "hacked" it by getting `UrlInstance` from Category object, getting secure and non-secure base URLs and replacing it according front-end setting:

```
private function getUrl(Category $category)
{
    $categoryUrl = $category->getUrl();

    if ($this->config->useSecureUrlsInFrontend($category->getStoreId()) === false) {
        return $categoryUrl;
    }

    $unsecureBaseUrl = $category->getUrlInstance()->getBaseUrl(['_secure' => false]);
    $secureBaseUrl = $category->getUrlInstance()->getBaseUrl(['_secure' => true]);

    if (strpos($categoryUrl, $unsecureBaseUrl) === 0) {
        return substr_replace($categoryUrl, $secureBaseUrl, 0, mb_strlen($unsecureBaseUrl));
    }

    return $categoryUrl;
}
```

So far it works fine.

If you have more elegant (less hacky) solution, please post it here. I'm happy to change the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

I used Jan's idea. But I had to get the `secue_base_url` for the store using `storeManagerInterface`. So I did something like this:

```
// using \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface storeManagerInterface
public function getCategoryUrl($category) {
    $categoryUrl = $category->getUrl();
    $unSecureBaseUrl = $this->storeManagerInterface->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_WEB, false);
    if (strpos($categoryUrl, $unSecureBaseUrl) === 0) {
        $secureBaseUrl = $this->storeManagerInterface->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_WEB, true);
        $categoryUrl = substr_replace($categoryUrl, $secureBaseUrl, 0, strlen($unSecureBaseUrl));
    }
    return $categoryUrl;
}
```